# Old version of script is run unless invoked with "sh scriptname"

Tags: bash, shell

I'm making a small edit to a shell script I use to mask password inputs like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Enter login and press [ENTER]\n"
read user

printf "Enter password and press [ENTER]\n"
read -s -p pass
```

With the `read -s -p pass` being the updated part.  For some reason I'm not seeing the changes when I run it normally by entering `script.sh` into the command line but I do see the changes when I run `sh script.sh`.  I've tried opening new terminal windows, and have run it in both ITerm and the default Mac terminal.  I'm far from a scripting master, does anyone know why I'm not seeing the changes without the prefix?

Comment: Did you try: `./script.sh` ?

Comment: Just plain `script.sh` will look for a file by that name in any of the directories in `$PATH`, not in the current directory. `sh script.sh` and `./script.sh` both run that file from the current directory. It's likely the first method running a different version of the script.

Comment: I figured that the old version was being cached somewhere.  Running `./script.sh` in the working directory runs the correct version, running just `script.sh` anywhere runs the old version.

Comment: Do you have an old version of `script.sh` somewhere on your `PATH`? You can find out with `type -a script.sh`

Comment: Yes, I can see it using that command, and that turned out to be the problem.  Appreciate everyones help very much.

Comment: @JonathonNordquist, btw, using `sh` makes this a POSIX sh script, not a bash script. Which is a problem, because `read -p` isn't a POSIX-specified feature, so it'll break whenever you're on a Linux distro with a baseline POSIX `/bin/sh` (like dash). Always use `bash yourscript` if the script shebang starts with `#!/bin/bash` so you're honoring the author's intent wrt. interpreter selection.

Comment: (For related reasons, using `.sh` as a file extension is in many circles considered misleading and bad practice for scripts, *especially* ones that aren't POSIX-compliant; even for scripts with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, though, using a file extension means you can't change your interpreter without needing to rename the file and thus modify everything that uses it; so there's consensus that extensions are the Right Thing only for files meant to be sourced rather than executed; see http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ for an essay on the topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a full or relative path to the script to make sure you're running what you think you're running.

If you are running it as simply `script.sh` then the shell will `PATH` environment variable lookup to locate it. To see which `script.sh` bash would be using in that case, run `type script.sh`.

### Relative Path

```sh
./script.sh
```

### Full Path

```sh
/path/to/my/script.sh
```

Comment: Yes, this jives with what others above have written, appreciate the full writeup.  `which script.sh` pointed me to a different directory than the one where I'd made my changes.  Updating it there as well did the trick, and now it's running properly.  I came here to get a fix and ended up learning about five new things.  Man I love this community.  You get an upvote and a green checkmark, if you're ever in Chicago I owe you a beer.

Comment: `type` is preferable to `which` -- the later is an external command and doesn't know anything about bash aliases, functions, cached PATH lookups, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy nice, didn't know that. I'll update the answer.