# Running a script after updating it still runs old script (pre-updated version)

Tags: bash, scripting, archlinux

I have a script (`a.sh`) in the folder `~/bin/`. Then I created a symbolic link (`a`) and copied it to `/usr/local/bin/`.

After I made a change to my script in `~/bin/`, I changed the directory to `~` and typed `a` (without the quotes). My shell still runs the old script.

To run script with my changes I have to type `. ~/bin/a.sh`.

I've found that re-creating the symbolic link, then copying it to `/usr/local/bin/` works, but it's a hassle to do that every time I made a change.

Is there some way to do this automatically?

A similar/same issue has been discussed before here:

[Old version of script is run unless invoked with "sh scriptname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716359/old-version-of-script-is-run-unless-invoked-with-sh-scriptname)

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. What command did you use to create the symbolic link? `ln -s`  or just `ln`? If you used just `ln` search Internet about the difference between symbolic soft and hard links. And what do you see when you type `ls -l /usr/local/bin/a`?

Comment: I used ln -s. 



If I do ls -l /usr/local/bin/a output is:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 50 Aug  8 22:14 /usr/local/bin/a

Comment: Please post all full commands that you used. Please kindly edit your question and add additional information there - comments are bad for code. `Is there someway to tell system, I've updated the script?` Are you __sure__ you copied the symbol link itself, and not the script that the symbolic links points to? Please post the command that you used to copy.

Comment: @dosfilesystem If you see `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 50 Aug 8 22:14 /usr/local/bin/a` then what you have here is a regular file, not a soft symbolic link. You somehow copied the original instead of linking.

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet That's spot on. I didn't realise doing 'cp source destination' with a symbolic link will copy the file linked by the symbolic link (not the symbolic link). So, I tried creating the symbolic link directly to /usr/local/bin and that worked. Or I could just do what KamilCuk suggests below and use the correct switches or better still put ~/bin in my PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You copied the file, not the symbolic link. To copy the symbolic link, tell it to `cp`.

```
cp --no-dereference link dest
```

But usually, just:

```
cp -d link dest
# or
cp -a link dest
```

---

Adding links in `/usr/local/bin` to location inside user home directory `~/bin` looks odd. If the script is user-local, just add `~/bin` to `PATH` and have it there. If the script is system global, do not have two locations of the script with confusing symlinks - consider having the script in `/usr/local/bin`. Consider researching GNU stow and chezmoi and other management software.

Comment: I was just doing 'cp a /usr/local/bin' which seems to have copied a.sh to /usr/local/bin as filename 'a'. If I skip the creating sym link within ~/bin and then copying but do it directly to /usr/local/bin and specify full paths all it well. So this works 'ln -s ~/bin/a.sh /usr/local/bin/a'. Take your point though I should just add ~/bin to my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

If you move a symlink, the link destination does not update. If you used a relative path, the moved symlink will be broken.

For example:

```sh
cd /tmp
mkdir foobar
cd foobar
touch afile
ln -s ./afile symlink
cd ..
cp -a foobar/symlink .
ls -l symlink
```

outputs

```sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 7 Aug  9 08:55 symlink -> ./afile
```

and "./afile" does not exist in the current directory.

IMO it's best to cd to the destination directory before creating symbolic links.